# find all defects and subtask under given story?

Tags: filter, jira, jql

I need to find all defects and subtask under given story. How can I find the same ?

Do i need to install any plugin or is it possible to JQL itself ?

Comment: Plus one for an interesting JQL question!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this requirement via JQL itself and there is no need of any additional plugins with JIRA.

First you need to have a filter that brings down to that one single UserStory which you want to query for bugs and subtasks. That should be implemented in this manner (something similar to this). Save that filter by a name so that you can refer it again - say 'MyFilter':

```
project = ABC AND issuetype = UserStory AND issuekey = ABC-12345
```

The next step is use this Filter in the following JQL to fetch what you require for:

```
issuetype in (Bug, SubTask) and issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf('filter = MyFilter')
```

You can provide the optional second parameter in the `linkedIssuesOf` `JQL` function (which is nothing but the link type) and if you choose not to, then it provides with all the tickets under the UserStory matching your `issuetype`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It says `issuetype in (Bug, SubTask) and issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf( key = HIXIND-29266)`

Comment: I didn't get you, are you saying that it doesn't work?